# How to specify python requests http put body?

Tags: python, http, put, httplib2, python-requests

I'm trying to rewrite some old python code with requests module.
The purpose is to upload an attachment.
The mail server requires the following specification :

```
https://api.elasticemail.com/attachments/upload?username=yourusername&api_key=yourapikey&file=yourfilename
```

Old code which works:

```
h = httplib2.Http()        
        resp, content = h.request('https://api.elasticemail.com/attachments/upload?username=omer&api_key=b01ad0ce&file=tmp.txt', 
        "PUT", body=file(filepath).read(), 
        headers={'content-type':'text/plain'} )
```

Didn't find how to use the body part in requests.

I managed to do the following:

```
 response = requests.put('https://api.elasticemail.com/attachments/upload',
                    data={"file":filepath},                         
                     auth=('omer', 'b01ad0ce')                  
                     )
```

But have no idea how to specify the body part with the content of the file.

Thanks for your help.
Omer.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Quoting from the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

> **data** – (optional) Dictionary or bytes to send in the body of the **Request**.

So this *should* work (not tested):

```
 filepath = 'yourfilename.txt'
 with open(filepath) as fh:
     mydata = fh.read()
     response = requests.put('https://api.elasticemail.com/attachments/upload',
                data=mydata,                         
                auth=('omer', 'b01ad0ce'),
                headers={'content-type':'text/plain'},
                params={'file': filepath}
                 )
```

Comment: This did not work for me (Python 3.8). I needed to use 'json' rather than 'data'. See answer below.

Answer (score 21):

I got this thing worked using Python and it's request module. With this we can provide a file content as page input value. See code below,

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://Client.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/87440'
headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json", 'Accept': "application/json"}
f = open("file.html", "r")
html = f.read()

data={}
data['id'] = "87440"
data['type']="page"
data['title']="Data Page"
data['space']={"key":"AB"}
data['body'] = {"storage":{"representation":"storage"}}
data['version']={"number":4}

print(data)

data['body']['storage']['value'] = html

print(data)

res = requests.put(url, json=data, headers=headers, auth=('Username', 'Password'))

print(res.status_code)
print(res.raise_for_status())
```

Feel free to ask if you have got any doubt.

---

**NB**: In this case the body of the request is being passed to the `json` kwarg.

Comment: This helped but a couple points: 1) you need to pass `headers=headers`. 2) you should elaborate on the fact that the `json` kwarg is the body in this case. 3) You are mixing python 2 and 3 in your print statements!! :)