# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 Web API Put request clears value

Tags: python, api, oauth, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm trying to use a put request to update Dynamics CRM. When I run the following python code I get a 204 response, but instead of updating a value it clears it. For example firstname gets updated to null instead of "WebApiUpdate".

```
import adal
import json
import urllib2
import requests

endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"
username = "example@example.com"
password = "password"
resource_uri = "https://orgname.crm.dynamics.com"

token_response = adal.acquire_token_with_username_password(endpoint,username,password,resource= resource_uri)
print token_response['accessToken']




payload = { "value": "WebApiUpdate"}
url = "http://xxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/contacts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001)/firstname"
headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer "+token_response['accessToken']}
r = requests.put(url,data=payload,headers=headers)
print r.content
```

Comment: That request looks fine to me. Do you have any plugins or synchronous workflows registered against contact?  Another avenue for investigation: turn on auditing at the system level, then turn on auditing for contact, reissue your request, then inspect the audit log for the record. Does is show that "WebApiUpdate" made it to the record and then got wiped out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. set the url to be `https://` instead of `http://`
2. set `data = payload` to `json = payload` in the request. ex:

   ```
   r = requests.put(url,json=payload,headers=headers)
   ```

**What was going wrong:**

1. The initial call, which included the payload (regardless of if it was set to data or json), received a response of `HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently`. In this response was a header with the new location. This location simply included `https://` in the url. Then my code sent out a second put request that went to the correct https url, had the correct header parameters, but did not include the payload. This caused my put request to not include the value to update to, so Microsoft Dynamics CRM set the value to null.
2. Microsoft Dynamics CRM requires the put request payload to be formatted in json. After I updated the link to be `https://` and the payload was included, it was formatted as `x-www-form-urlencoded`.That means the payload was appended to the request as `value=WebApiUpdate`. This caused a reply of `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`. Changing the payload to be formatted as json means the payload will be appended to the request as `{"value": "WebApiUpdate"}`.

**How I solved it:**

1. I set my program to output the http put call it was making by adding the below code that I found from this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-http-request-thats-being-sent-by-my-python-application). I then noticed that there were two non identical put calls and went from there.

   ```
   import logging

   try:
       import http.client as http_client
   except ImportError:
       # Python 2
       import httplib as http_client
   http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
   logging.basicConfig() 
   logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
   requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
   requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
   requests_log.propagate = True
   ```
2. I read the documentation on the request method [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#main-interface) which I found on this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832639/how-to-specify-python-requests-http-put-body)